Can a soft switching SSR with an AC load work without a snubber?
I'm trying to design a general purpose solid state relay for a variety of AC resistive and inductive loads namely heaters, motors and solenoids.
I'm aiming for low heat dissipation and I'm not worried about the cost to some extents so I'm looking toward 2 back to back N-channel MOSFETs with an isolated ac-dc power supply and an isolated gate driver.
For example, 2 of those MOSFETs: IMBG120R040M2H
Based on what TI shows here in an appnote:

Self-Powered AC Solid State Relay With MOSFETs
Now reading online, it seems like I might need something called a snubber circuit depending on the load I'm switching and the MOSFETs I'm using.
As a naïve firmware engineer I'm thinking to myself, instead of going in and trying to understand the math behind the snubber circuit, why not monitor the AC voltage and the AC current with a microcontroller and do the following:

Switch ON when voltage crosses 0 V
Switch OFF when current reaches 0 A

Would that plan work out?

Francois - Hi, You mentioned a TI appnote, but specifically where did the image originally come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. Assuming the original source is online in a PDF, please [edit] the question and add the PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. PDF title + URL). TY

Two aspects to consider: first, dissipation.
Triacs and SCRs have a quite constant voltage drop across them when conducting, so losses are proportional to current. MOSFETs act as resistors, so losses are \$ RI^2 \$.
In the MOSFET case, when current gets high, the square means you'll need really low RdsON (or several in parallel) to keep losses low.
Using your quoted MOSFET as example, with RdsON of 60 mOhm when hot, two in series to make an AC switch results in 120mOhms resistance. Let's compare it with BTA216 triac:

It looks like the MOSFETs will have higher dissipation above about 10A. This is for pure sine wave current, it would be different (worse for the FET) for a spiky low power factor current waveform.
FETs are much faster of course, and they can be turned off, but they are also much more expensive and require more expensive and complex drive.
Next is turn off behavior.
Unless you use an elaborate scheme with a current sense and comparator to turn off the MOSFET when current reaches zero (this comes for free with a triac), when the load is inductive and it turns off, without a snubber the MOSFET will have to absorb all the energy stored in the load inductance. It can do that either by switching slowly so it has time to absorb the inductive stored energy during turn-off (at this time it works in linear mode) or if it turns off quickly it will do that by going into avalanche mode.
If the inductance is high this can be a problem, as it will cause the MOSFET to heat up. In normal conduction RdsON has a positive tempco, so hotter areas of the FET will take less current, which avoids hotspots. When the FET goes in linear mode the tempco reverses, so hotter areas on the chip will take more current. This can lead to hotspots and a blown FET.
The datasheet usually specifies a maximum avalanche energy (in mJ) starting from a cold chip. If the chip is hot when it occurs, the maximum allowed energy will be lower, this has to be taken into account.
Snubbers are annoying: they take up a lot of board space, dissipate, and due to the cap between input and output they always leak a little bit of power into the load even when the switch is off. But they will avoid this problem. Another solution is to use a TVS instead of the snubber to absorb the inductive energy. If the FET doesn't switch often, the TVS has the advantage of starting from a cold temperature when it takes the energy pulse, whereas the MOSFET is hot. But it should still be sized to absorb the expected maximum energy. On the other hand, a triac dissipates the inductive energy in the load's internal resistance, so it doesn't really care.
So... yeah... triacs do seem like an obsolete crusty tech compared to modern SiC, but they do the job for very low cost and complexity...

You want to avoid transients when the MOSFETs are off at any time for example in the case of inductive loads and in sinusoidal regime. Although I have not tried it, a solution like the one shown here comes to mind where the two switches switch in a complementary way:


This works when the switches commutate (go from on to off, or vice versa) on par or faster than the natural RL or RC time constant at the switch node (note, not due to C1 or L1, but the junction capacitance and stray inductance of the switches and loop thereof). But you cannot get this from PV MOS type switches, which typically take several milliseconds to switch.

that's an idea that came to me on the spot. So why don't you suggest us your idea? Besides, Francois didn't mention a PV system.

Written answers are not a prerequisite to making constructive comments.  But I guess if you insist -- as you can see from my score, I have written many. (Whether they're any good, is another matter; frankly, to me, the score is just meaningless internet points, and I won't claim to hold this number as some kind of objective authority score.) Indeed, the best that can be done in this text box is to help make others aware of possible oversights.  Readers and answerers alike are welcome to heed or decline such commentary as they see fit.

But you may be interested to know that the type of device implied by the OP (a prepackaged, LED input, bidirectional MOS switch output, AC/DC SSR), uses an integrated PV (photovoltaic) gate driver, i.e., a stack of photodiodes, illumunated by the LED, to deliver approx. 8V at a few µA. The lack of discharge resistor or other drive circuitry in your figure, also seems to support a scheme like this as the intention -- but the astute reader will note, neither post specifies clearly what is intended, and this has been left ambiguous and open to interpretation.

So, as you can see, given this (I can only assume intended) space of ambiguity, I've chosen an example product that fits neatly within that space. Readers may make a similar choice or interpretation -- or, very different choices would be equally valid.
